# Adding id to CSS tags in CakePHP while all CSS filenames are in an array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to assign an id to loaded CSS in CakePHP. How to assign the id to CSS using the CakePHP HTML helper?

While loading the single CSS:

```
echo $this->Html->css('......');
```

While loading multiple CSS:

```
$all_css = array('first', 'second', '....');
echo $this->Html->css($all_css);
```

Comment: if you mean `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="asdfasdf" ...` please edit the question to clarify that. Otherwise, what do you mean?

Comment: Why would you want ids on style tags?

Comment: @Juhana I want the ids on style tags. The below answer is for the single tag only, I know that. But I want to know for multiple style tag.

Comment: Yes, but I was asking why do you need them.

Comment: Some bootstrap css or script need to place id's hence this question has come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loading a single css you can do

```
echo $this->Html->css('foo', array('id' => 'your_css_id'));
```

I don't know how to do this with multiple css (unless you want to set the same id to all the tags but I don't think it's your case)